# Yii infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, yii

I have implemented Yii infinite scroll. its working fine without Jquery. 
 If i add J query Yii infinite scroll not working.

In my project i am using bootstrap collapse. in bootstrap collapse toggle is not working without jquery.
I am using version is j query-2.0.3 i also used lowest version also. am facing same problem. please give me tips to overcome this issue.

i attached my project screen shot. which is menu is not working.

```
  <script type="application/javascript" src="css/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you give us an error or something?

Answer (score 1):

```
Just use $.noconflict(); because its a conflict issue
```

Comment: i added $.noconflict(); in script which is not working